# Objective-c/iOS - Open local html file with Safari

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, safari

I have an HTML file save in a temporary directory like that :

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *documentDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory();
NSString *documentPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mydocument.html"];
[fileManager createFileAtPath:documentPath contents:myHTMLDocumentData attributes:nil];
```

The document is created in my temporary file. After it, I want to open this document in Safari but it doesn't work :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentPath];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Nothing happen at screen, no error... 
However, if I replace "url" by @"http://google.fr", Safari is launched with google.fr and I can access to my temporary file by typing the url "file://localhost..../myHtmlDocument.html" in Safari.

Hope you can help me

Comment: if you iOS device has internet connectivity, put it on the web and open it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot open a document with resides in your app bundle through Safari (please, see [iOS Security Model](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH9-SW7)).

What you need is using an `UIWebView` to display your document content inside your app using `– loadHTMLString:baseURL:`; e.g.:

```
UIWebView* webView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:rect] autorelease];
[webView loadHTMLString:myHTMLSource baseURL:nil];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Answer (score 2):

i dont think you can achieve that, since both `UIApplication openURL`: and `UIDocumentInteractionController` will not open local files inside your bundle

Do the following instead, in your `viewDidLoad`

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self addSubview:webView];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: documentPath]];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```