# OpenURL to a file in NSBundle

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, safari, openurl

I have a file, which i want to open in safari (or call it view in safari).
I add this file to my bundle resources.

and do the following:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tryFile.txt" ofType:nil inDirectory:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path];
NSLog(@"path: %@ \n url:%@ \n can open url:%d",path,url,[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]);
BOOL didGo = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
NSLog(@"didgo?: %d",didGo);
```

Of course, as the sandboxed environment says, I am not able to open the file ins safari. It says, `canOpenURL` as `yes` but then `didGo` is `NO`.

How can I do this without setting up a local server. Please suggest.
Should I keep the data stored in a variable and then open an html page with that data...or what?

**EDIT:**
These are the logs:

```
path: /var/mobile/Applications/C78C7CD8-22C7-468A-AA5D-AF22C6042378/TryApp.app/tryFile.txt 
url:file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/C78C7CD8-22C7-468A-AA5D-AF22C6042378/TryApp.app/tryFile.txt 
can open url:1



didgo?: 0
```

**PLEASE NOTE** opening the file in a webview is not an option. The requirement wants it to be opened in safari. And anyways, this example is of a text file...the filethat may be opened can be anything, and webview does not support all file types.

Comment: what *does* open in Safari when "`openURL`" is called?

Comment: load the file in a webView

Comment: @NikitaP  Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035564/objective-c-ios-open-local-html-file-with-safari , you need to open it in UIWebview

Comment: You can observe the path it is `file://..` to open in safari it should be `http://..`

Comment: @prasaddevadiga: yup I know. That is why I was hoping if the data can be converted to an html string or something, that can be passed to open in the safari

Comment: @NikitaP hmm. You can not open even the html file which are stored inside the bundle.

Answer (score 2):

The txt file resides within your application sandbox. The URL that you are trying to load in Safari will not get loaded due to security in iOS. [Read more about it here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH9-SW7) 
As a workaround you can use a `UIWebView` in your application and open the file in that.

Cheers!
Amar.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to setup a server or open the page in a `UIWebView` inside the app.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tryFile.txt" ofType:nil inDirectory:nil];

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
```

This code is for open url in directly in safari OR you can use Webview and direct open url in your webview.thanks