# Flex 4 mobile ios open a file from application properties in browser

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flex4, flex4.5

I am saving a file on the application storage directory and I would like to open it with the ios browser by doing navigateToURL(new URLRequest(file.nativePath)). But the files does not open. I know it should work because if I navigate to google the browser opens correctly. So the problem is the file path I place in the browser for the file.

Does someone know what is the file path I shoud place on the browser to access the file on the application storage directory.

Comment: What happens if you try to open that file with FileStream.open() and do a trace(fileStream.readUTFBytes(fileStream.bytesAvailable);?

Comment: How are you creating the file path URL when you try to use navigateToURL?

Comment: I used both: navigateToURL(new URLRequest(file.nativePath)) and navigateToURL(new URLRequest(file.url)) neither worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Objective-c/iOS - Open local html file with Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035564/objective-c-ios-open-local-html-file-with-safari) and [View local HTML files using web browser on iPad](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91398/view-local-html-files-using-web-browser-on-ipad) on apple.stackexchange.com.  Basically, the ios security model prevents this.

What you can do is use `StageWebView`:

```
 var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
 webView.stage = this.stage;
 webView.viewPort = new Rectangle( 0, 50, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight );
 webView.loadURL(file.nativePath); // or file.url
```

StageWebView displays on top of all other components in your application, so you'll want to leave a margin (like the 50 pixel offset I included above) to leave room for a button to dismiss the StageWebView.

See also the [StageWebView docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html)

Comment: They will have the same issue with `StageWebView`. The issue is not the file itself, but the path being used. Although I do believe they will have to switch to StageWebView anyway for the reasons you mentioned.

Comment: @Josh Janusch it works on the desktop debug mode but not when I debug on the device. The browser appears Blank. I don't understand. So I am using webView like Brian said because of security issues. I tried webView.loadURL(file.nativePath) and file.url. Finally, I tried with the hack from Josh. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that your path is incorrect. Basically, `File.nativePath` and `File.url` will both give you a URL that uses `app://` or `app-storage://` (or any number of others), both relative to the app itself. When you try to open that link in a browser or in `StageWebView` or in `StageVideo`, the link becomes relative to the browser/video player, rather than your app. That is why you cannot link to the files properly.

There is a simple fix, thankfully. I found this (which may be considered a "hack", but it works) in an Adobe Forums post a long time ago. I wish I had a source, but I don't:

```
trace( new File( file.nativePath ).url );
```

Try that. It basically creates a new File using the actual native path of the file. The URL of this file is the *full* path to the file, rather than being relative to the app in any way. As mentioned by Brian, you may end up needing to use `StageWebView` instead, but this will give you the proper pathing.

As a quick note, this does not work on Android if I remember correctly. On Android, you want to use either `nativePath` or `url` directly. But this little workaround will work on iOS (An app I currently have in the app store is using it without issue)

Comment: Ok, the problem is that I am trying to open an xml file which should be transformed with an xsl file. This works on ADL but not on the sandbox of my ipad. Whith a normal HTML file it works.

Comment: Do you guys know a way to apply an XSL transformation offline with ActionScript.